# MaxentVariableSelectoin error in rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer", :

Tags: java, maxent

I'm using the MaxEntVariableSelection package and repeatedly getting the following error when trying to execute `VariableSelection`  even after setting all the things as explained in `MaxentVAriableSelection` Vignette. Any help to skip this error is much appreciated.

These occurrence/background CSV files do not contain NAs or Numbering column before the "species" column and have SWD format. All the files, raster layers and maxent.jar set in the same working directory. Raster layers are separate and in `.asc` format.

```
MaxentVariableSelection::VariableSelection(maxent="C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/maxent.jar", 
                                       outdir="C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2", 
                                     gridfolder="/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/30sclippedascii",
                                       occurrencelocations="C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/xocc_all.csv",
                                       backgroundlocations="C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/xbg_all.csv",
                                       additionalargs="nolinear noquadratic noproduct nothreshold noautofeature",
                                       contributionthreshold=5, 
                                       correlationthreshold=0.9,
                                       betamultiplier=seq(2,6,0.5))

Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In system(paste("java -jar", maxent, "-o", outdir, "-j", gridfolder,  :
  running command 'java -jar C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/maxent.jar -o     C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2 -j /Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/30sclippedascii/ -s C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2/xocc_all.csv_VariableSubset.csv -e C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2/xbg_all.csv_VariableSubset.csv plots=false writeplotdata=false visible=false autorun=true randomseed=true writebackgroundpredictions=false replicates=10 replicatetype=subsample randomtestpoints=50 redoifexists writemess=false writeclampgrid=false askoverwrite=false pictures=false outputgrids=false -b 2 nolinear noquadratic noproduct nothreshold noautofeature' had status 1


2: In system(paste("java -jar", maxent, "-o", outdir, "-j", gridfolder,  :
      running command 'java -jar C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/maxent.jar -o C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2 -j /Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/30sclippedascii/ -s C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2/xocc_all.csv_VariableSubset.csv -e C:/Users/Piyali/Desktop/msc_paper/R_SDM/outputtest2/xbg_all.csv_VariableSubset.csv plots=false writeplotdata=false visible=false autorun=true randomseed=true writebackgroundpredictions=false redoifexists writemess=false writeclampgrid=false askoverwrite=false pictures=false outputformat=raw -b 2 nolinear noquadratic noproduct nothreshold noautofeature' had status 1


Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",  : 
      Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this error in the future, check whether the **column names of the variables** in occurrence/background CSV files are exactly similar to the **names of raster layers** you have provided.